# Trying to add a listener to a model (backed by a TDB2 dataset)

Tags: jena

After a little research, `org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphMonitor` looked the way to go.
To my understanding I have to crate a DatasetGraph wrapped by the DatasetGraphMonitor, use this graph to create a Model and all the modifications to the model are now notified to my DatasetChanges object.
So that's what I'm doing:

```
//create a Dataset backed by TBD2
Dataset dataset = TDB2Factory.connectDataset(location);

//wrap the dataset with a DatasetGraphMonitor and obtain a DatasetGraph
DatasetGraph datasetGraph = new DatasetGraphMonitor(dataset.asDatasetGraph(), new DatasetChanges() {
  @Override
  public void start() {
  }
  @Override
  public void reset() {
  }
  @Override
  public void finish() {
  }
  @Override
  public void change(QuadAction qaction, Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
    LOG.info("Dataset change: "+qaction);
  }
});

//create a model using the DatasetGraphMonitor as underlying graph
Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(datasetGraph.getDefaultGraph());

//run an insert sparql query to add new triples to the triplestore (this really is in a write transaction, maybe I'm oversimplifying here)
UpdateAction.parseExecute(sparqlQuery, model);
```

well, you guessed that already: `change` never gets called.
Any idea about what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DatasetGraphMonitor is for monitoring actions on the dataset. Getting the default graph, making it a model, doesn't trigger that machinery. (If it did, you'd get a "not in transaction" exception). The returns graph does straight to the core database.

Instead, either:

1. Wrap the graph from datasetGraph.getDefaultGraph() with GraphWrapper and put
   the monitoring code on the various add/delete methods.
2. Do the update (in a transaction) on the datasetGraph.

Comment: Solution 1 seems very similar to what I'm doing: if I understand it right (which is difficult, given the missing documentation) DatasetGraphMonitor is already a wrapper that I'm using abound a  graph connected to the database. From there I create a model using the wrapped graph as underlying storage.

Comment: DatasetGraphMonitor is a wrapper on a DatasetGraph, not a graph.

Comment: Yes but the model is created on the default graph of the wrapped dataset graph. It is not intuitive the way this thing works.

Comment: I ended up wrapping a DatasetGraph to intercept commits and make it return a wrapped Graph from getGraph/getDefaultGraph to intercept additions to the model. It's working but I'm not sure it's really the best solution (btw it's here https://github.com/cars-team/semanticengine/blob/master/src/main/java/it/gaussproject/semanticengine/jena/TransactionEnqueuingDatasetGraphWrapper.java).